# get out links from nutch

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I am using nutch 1.3 to crawl a website. I want to get a list of urls crawled, and urls originating  from a page.

I get list of urls crawled using readdb command.

```
bin/nutch readdb crawl/crawldb -dump file
```

Is there a way to find out urls that are on a page by reading crawldb or linkdb ?

in the `org.apache.nutch.parse.html.HtmlParser` I see outlinks array, I am wondering if there is a quick way to access it from command line.

Comment: To be precise you mean finding the outlinks of a given page. I don't know that you can do that from the command line. You should be able in writing & map/reduce job... not that difficult as I found out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From command line, you can see the outlinks by using [readseg](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch_readseg) with -dump or -get option. For example,

```
bin/nutch readseg -dump crawl/segments/20110919084424/ outputdir2 -nocontent -nofetch - nogenerate -noparse -noparsetext

less outputdir2/dump
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this with **readlinkdb** command. It gives you all the inlinks and outlinks to and from a url.

```
bin/nutch readlinkdb <linkdb> (-dump <out_dir> | -url <url>)
```

linkdb: This is the linkdb directory we wish to read and obtain information from.

out_dir: This parameter dumps the whole linkdb to a text file in any out_dir we wish to specify.

url: The -url arguement provides us with information about a specific url. This is written to System.out.

```
e.g. 

bin/nutch readlinkdb crawl/linkdb -dump myoutput/out1
```

For more information refer to 
http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch%20readlinkdb